# Django - Setting variable inside a template (or calling IF statement where argument is a function)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a (template tag - simple_tag) function, which takes 1 argument (and context) and returns a string.
So calling `{% myfunction var1 %}` returns a string (depended on var1).

Now I want to use this inside a if statement, something like: `{% if myfunction var1 == 'some string' %}`.
Obviously that doesn't work, so I have tried to firstly save returned string to a variable and then use it in if statement.

But `{% myfunction var1 as var2 %}` doesn't work because it treats "as var2" as a second function argument and I get the "received too many positional arguments" error.

I have tried the "with" statement also, but it doesn't work either...

So how can I save the function return value to a variable OR how can I directly use a function inside if statement ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register your template tag using `django.template.Library.assignment_tag()` and then use `{% myfunction var1 as var2 %}` in your template.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags

Comment: Tnx, Now I know how to save something to a variable. But now I have to save it first, and then use it again. I was hoping for something that returns value (and displays it) in addition to saving it.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a filter instead of a tag. Then you can use it in an if statement:

```
{% if var1|myfunction == 'some string' %}
```

as well as just standalone:

```
{{ var1|myfunction }}
```

Comment: That is a good solution but as far as I know, filters can't take context like tags. (I can provide context as an additional argument but that will just complicate my code)